# How to create a Resteasy MultipartFormDataInput from InputStream?

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying to get a `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput` from the MessageBodyReader. How do I do it?

```
@Provider
@Consumes("mulipart/form-data")
public class UserMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<User> {
    @Override
    public User readFrom(Class<User> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                         MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                         InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
       // parse here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just look at the source code for the reader that already exists?

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?